# Finding transfer functions from a system of multiple inputs

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, transfer-function, laplace-transform

If I have a system: $$sX(s) = AX(s)+BY(s)+CZ(s)$$ How would I find the transfer functions $\frac{X(s)}{Y(s)}$ and $\frac{X(s)}{Z(s)}$?

Do I simply disregard one of the inputs? I am quite confused and not able to find any information on this.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A (linear time-invariant) system with multiple inputs and a single output is usually characterized by the following input/output relation:

$$Y(s)=\sum_{i=1}^m H_i(s)X_i(s)$$

where $m$ is the number of inputs, $Y(s)$ is the Laplace transform of the output, $H_i(s)$ is the transfer function relating the $i^{th}$ input to the output, and $X_i(s)$ is the transform of the $i^{th}$ input.

Note that

$$H_i(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X_i(s)},\qquad X_j(s)=0,\quad j\neq i$$

Now try to identify the individual transfer functions $H_i(s)$ from the equation in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the system is linear (it doesn't have to be time-invariant for this bit to hold) then its responses to multiple inputs are separable.  If it's LTI then transfer functions are applicable; in that case you can compute $\frac X Y$ while holding $Z = 0$, then compute $\frac X Z$ while holding $Y = 0$.